# set two python paths in the some Django app in pycharm

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I have create a Django app and working nice using pycharm editor in windows.

my app :

```
myapp
  - __init__.py
  - settings.py
  - urls.py
  - wsgi.py
app.name
  -  __init__.py
  -  admin.py
  -  apps.py
  -  forms.py
  -  modelspy
  -  test.py
  -  urls.py
  -  views.py
```

now I need to add new python file in app.name to call some function in `views.py`

like this:

```
myfynction(input,output)  #that in views.
```

---

```
app.name
  -  __init__.py
  -  admin.py
  -  apps.py
  -  forms.py
  -  modelspy
  -  test.py
  -  urls.py
  -  myfunction.py
  -  views.py
```

the problem is the additional `myfunction.py` file have different python path `python.exe` from all Django app.

can I set two python paths in the some Django app in pycharm ?

Comment: You have to do a subprocess.call I don't see other way around this

Comment: I don't think there's a good way to do this in any form of python, let alone django or pycharm. Why do you want to do such a thing?

Comment: because I need to mix python version